# Performance Issue on Tablets

Tags: libgdx

I am developing a penalty shoot game using libgdx 1.1.0 and spine. The game screen which contains 2 spine animations, one scene2d stage for button and labels, and spriteBatch rendering for remaining visual objects. I have only one asset as 768x1280 which is scaled according to screen size. Game runs between 50-60 fps on android devices under 5,6 inch screen, but tablet performance is under 35 fps.

I have changed filters of my atlas files from Min(Linear), Mag(Linear) to Min(Nearest), Mag(Nearest) and performance was better as 40fps but this time image visual quality was poor.

Is there any configuration I missed about performance on tablets?
I really appreciate it if you can share your suggestions about performance especially on tablet devices?

Comment: You might try an Internet search on your tablet to see if it's known for having an underpowered GPU. You might get a modest improvement if you turn blending off when drawing the background (if you haven't already).

Answer (score 0):

The `TextureFilter` which is used here is the magnification filter, as the `Texture` you have has a lower resolution, then the place it will use up.
The `TextureFilter` you used (linear) fetches the 4 nearest pixels and out of their colors it calculates the color for the current pixel. So for every pixel on screen it has to fetch 4 pixel.
The filter you use now, the nearest filter, fetches only the nearest pixel, so it fetches one pixel per pixel on screen, this costs less performance but has lower quality to.
The solution is to use MipMapping. You simply create a MipMap chain, which is a chain of your image going from 1024*1024 to 512*512 to 256*256 px and so on. I am not sure if you need to do that yourself (at runtime) or if libgdx does this for you. Then you need to use the right `TextureFilter`, which is one of the following:

•**GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST**, this will fetch the best fitting image from the mip map chain based on the pixel/texel ratio and then sample the texels with a nearest filter.

•**GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST**, this will fetch the best fitting image from the mip map chain based on the pixel/texel ratio and then sample the texels with a linear filter. Ya, that’s no type you specify the mip map filter last (NEAREST here) and the actual texel filter first

•**GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR**, this will fetch the two best fitting images from the mip map chain and then sample the nearest texel from each of the two images, combining them to the final output pixel

•**GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR**, this will fetch the two best fitting images from the mip map chain and then sample the four nearest texels from each of the two images, combining them to the final output pixel

Another little performance boost can be created by disabeling blending when rendering the background, as there it is not needed. And if there are objects out of your camras field of view, do not `draw` them. Before calling `spritebatch.draw(texture, pos.x, pos.y)` make sure `pos.x` and `pos.y` are visible.

Something to read about [TextureFilters](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1403)

I hope it helps!